How to make Two RDS Instances in the same subnet resolve endpoints to private IP
I've set up a replication instance in the same subnets as my master. They are both allowing traffic from within the entire VPC, and are allowing egress.
When setting up a subscription on the replication instance, the request times out with the error showing that it's trying the endpoint's public IP.
Both instances have public access set to ON as it's required.
Any tips as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated
Note that existing EC2 instances in my VPC are connecting to the master privately.
RROR:  could not connect to the publisher: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "dbname.randomstring.region.rds.amazonaws.com" (PUBLIC_IP) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Many thanks
I've tried allowing both SGs and redeploying the replication instance again

Does this help answer your question?

Is your database being accessed outside the VPC? If not, then the database should be set to Publicly accessible = No and then only private IP addresses will be used.
